# Issue with recursive function, repeating returns

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm having an issue with getting to grips using recursive functions. 
I've had this happen a couple of times now but I've just done awkward workarounds.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fib(int n);

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    i = fib(i);
    cout << i << endl;
    system("pause");
}

int fib(int n) {
    cout << n << endl;
    if (n <= 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the output is far from what it should be, by following the breakpoints I can see that once the function has finished as it should, the final line under the else statement is still being called. 
I'm sure it's something simple I'm doing wrong but I'd be grateful if someone could shed some light on this!

Comment: What do you mean `the final line under the else statement is still being called`?

Comment: You could specify what exactly is the wrong output you are getting

Answer (score 1):

The function is correct, even if you should decide if `F(1)` should be `fib(0)` or `fib(1)` since in your implementation `fib(0) == 0` but the first element of the serie is 1, not 0.

Apart from that I don't see any problem, the problem you are experiencing is present, for example, in LLDB, where a `return` statement placed in the middle of a function makes the debugger "pass by" the last instruction of the function (but this is just caused by the mapping between code and underlying binary), it is not really executing the statement.

Comment: The first element of the series more commonly 0 than 1 (look at sites such as OEIS).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your confusion about the trace, I think I can explain.

In `fib(5)`, you recursively invoke `fib(4)`. After all of the recursion done there is resolved and you're back in `fib(5)`... you then recursively invoke `fib(3)` so you have a lot more calculation to do... and then once that's done and you're back in `fib(5)`, you still have an addition to do before you're done and can return.

(disclaimer: the above order isn't guaranteed; e.g. compiler might decide to have your program compute `fib(3)` first and then `fib(4)` after)

In the calculation of `fib(5)`, the final return line gets executed *seven* times across the different calls. For large `n` you'd have a tremendous number of recursive calls to work through; this example is one of the usual demonstrations of the benefits of dynamic programming and/or memoization. (or even just carefully restructuring the recursion so you don't have a tree of recursive calls; e.g. have a recursively implemented function return a pair consisting of both the `n`-th *and* the `n-1`-th Fibonacci numbers)

Answer (score 0):

hope this would help..

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Fibo(int);

int main(void) {
int number;

cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
cin >> number;
if (number < 0)
    cout << "That is not a positive integer.\n";
else
    cout << " Fibonacci is: " << Fibo(number) << endl;
}

int Fibo(int x) 
{
    if (x < 2){
     return x;
    }     
    return (Fibo (x - 1) + Fibo (x - 2));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it, but it might be a "dangling else problem". Not using curly braces for conditional blocks is a bad coding style. Do yourself a favor and write sth. like

```
if( n <= 0 )
{
    return( 0 );
}
else if( n == 1 )
{
    return( 1 );
}
else
{
    return( fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 ) );
}
```

My suspicion is that your code is interpreted as

```
if( n <= 0 )
{
    return( 0 );
}
else
{
    if( n == 1 )
    {
        return( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        return( fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 ) );
    }
}
```

Without curly braces, your code is ambigious. I do not know which interpretation of your code fragment is favored by the compiler. You can easily check whether this is the problem by introducing the braces.

Comment: Both of those blocks of code, as well as OP's, are logically identical.

Comment: @Barry: Oh, you are right, didn't notice that :p. My fault. Still a bad coding style ;9.